# how to compile with Visual Studio 2008 when Visual Studio 2010 is installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to build mrjbq7's wrapper for TA-Lib for Python. After several attempts, I'm fairly sure the wrapper won't build because I have Visual Studio 2010, but my Python is looking for the compiler from Visual Studio 2008. Is it possible to get only the compiler? I have a feeling I may need to install Visual Studio 2008 side by side (saw another thread said this works with no problem), but would prefer to avoid it if possible. Is it possible?
More info:
Visual Studio 2010 Express installed
Windows 7
Python 2.7.3
pythonxy27 also installed
Reason to suspect it is compiler version:
a - last error I get is reference to unknown _ftol2_sse_, which other threads have said is due to using the wrong compiler
b - sys.version for MSC v. is 1500, which is for MSVC 9.0 (used a couple of lines from distutils\cygwincompiler.py in an interpreter to find this)

I hope that's all required info, I'll add more if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need Visual Studio installed at all to compile Python extensions.  Install the appropriate Windows SDK (for Python 2.7 that would be [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138)).  Then, using the Windows SDK command prompt, convince distutils to use MSVC 2008:

```
set MSSdk=1
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1 
setenv /Release
```

You should then be able to then install via setup.py

Comment: Thanks -- it gets a little farther, now I get error: "build\lib.win32-2.7\talib.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 391 unresolved externals      
error: command 'link.exe' failed with exit status 1120". I'll start a new search for how to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help Luis, from there I found a solution to the link.exe 1120 error:
1 - get Windows SDK from Luis post above
2 - go to the folder for Visual Studio 9 bin (mine was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin)
3 - open the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt
4 - change directory to mrjdb7's folder
5 - in command prompt, enter 'python setup.py install'

At this point, you should get an error: "cannot find vcvarsall.bat"

6 - copy and paste vcvar32.bat
7 - rename it vcvarsall.bat

At this point, it still won't work. It is a problem in a distutils python file

8 - navigate to the distutils folder (mine: C:\Python27\Lib\distutils)
9 - open msvc9compiler.py
10 - look for function "def find_vcvarsall(version):"  (mine: line 219)
11 - towards end of function, look for this line: 'vcvarsall = os.path.join(productdir, "vcvarsall.bat")'  (mine: line 257)
12 - replace with:  vcvarsall = os.path.join(productdir, r"bin\vcvarsall.bat")

The problem I found, msvc9compiler.py was looking one folder up from where the vcvarsall.bat file is, it should have looked in the \bin folder.